# How to make arrays in html horizontal table each array in 2 columns

Tags: php

2 arrays with different length

```
$status = array(
          array("up","down","down","up"),
          array("down","up","up","down"));

$room = array("RM101", "RM102","RM103","RM104","RM105", "RM106","RM107","RM108");
```

How can we have 2 columns, Top headers as `$room` array and row as `$status`.

The table should look like this:

[image: This is how the table should look like]

Please help me to solve this problem, I am new to PHP programming.

Please see the coding below which I did try.

```
 <?PHP
function room(){
    $n = 0;
    $rooms = array("RM101","RM102","RM103","RM104","RM105","RM106","RM107","RM108");
    {
        if ($n % 24 == 0) { 
        echo '<tr><td>'.$rooms[$m].'</td>';   
        }
        else 
        {
        echo '<td>'.$rooms[$m].'</td>'; 
        }
        $n++;
    }
}

function status(){
    $c=0;
    $nodes = array('http://x.x.xx.xx/rpFirstPageStatistics.html','http://x.x.xx.xx/rpFirstPageStatistics.html');
    $node_count = count($nodes);

    $curl_arr = array();
    $master = curl_multi_init();

    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
    {
    $Username = "xxx";
    $Password = "xxx";

        $url =$nodes[$i];
        $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$Username:$Password");  
        curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);

    }

    do {
        curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
    } while($running > 0);

    for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
    {
        $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
        preg_match_all('~<\/td><TD  width="65">(.*?)<\/td>~s', $results, $status); 
        foreach ($status as $value => $values){
        }
        foreach (array_slice($values,2) as $x=>$x_value){
            if ($c % 24 == 0) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$x_value.'</td>';  
            }else {
                echo '<td>'.$x_value.'</td>'; 
            }
            $c++;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I'm not sure the edit you made has made the question clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) to help you with pretty much all of this.

You can join the subarrays in `$status` together into one array with 8 items using [`array_merge(...$status)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). If your PHP is too old to have the [`...`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) operator, you can use [`call_user_func_array("array_merge", $status)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

Assuming that the `$status` array contains, in total, the same number of items as the `$room` array, you can then combine them into a list with the rooms as the keys and the statuses as the values with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). Then you have an array like this:

```
["RM101" => "up", "RM102" => "down", "RM103" => "down", ...]
```

To split it into rows with two columns, use [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) with the `$preserve_keys` flag set to true.

```
[["RM101" => "up", "RM102" => "down"], ["RM103" => "down", ...], ...]
```

Now the array is broadly in the structure you want, it's just a case of looping over the rows and outputting HTML. In each block we can use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the pair of room names, and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) (this isn't strictly necessary) to get the pair of statuses, and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join the array together into a string.

Putting it all together you get

```
$status = array(
          array("up","down","down","up"),
          array("down","up","up","down"));

$room = array("RM101", "RM102","RM103","RM104","RM105", "RM106","RM107","RM108");

echo "<table>";
foreach (array_chunk(array_combine($room, array_merge(...$status)), 2, true)
         as $block) {
    echo "<tr><th>" . implode("</th><th>", array_keys($row)) . "</th></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>" . implode("</td><td>", array_values($row)) . "</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you Matt Raines. This is exactly what i needed. SO rocks

Comment: Is it possible to color all the td which contains the value "down"; Do i need to use Javascript or is there a workaround

Comment: You should probably open a new question which deals with this in a specific way. But, yes, it is possible either with Javascript or with PHP. If you do it in PHP you will not be able to use `implode` any more. Instead you should use `foreach` to loop over the values in `$row` and output a different class or style attribute for your `<td>` flag if the value is "down".

Answer (score -1):

Try the below format:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Width</th>
        <th>Material</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th><img /></th>
        <td>50mm</td>
        <td>Plastic</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
$similar_com .= "<tr>";
$similar_com .= "<td><img style='width: 100px; height: 100px;' src='$row->image_url' alt='$row->model_no' /><br />$row->name</td>";
$similar_com .= "<td>$row->width mm</td>";
...
}
```